# Bitbucket pipelines keep failing on ZLIB install/discovery for php image

Tags: php, bitbucket, pipeline, zlib

I have bitbucket pipelines failing all of a sudden due to issues with the php zip library (yaml file hasn't been touched in years and builds were successful a few weeks ago)

I've tried multiple changes with the php image (using an apache version as well as an fpm) and I've tried with configuration changes to use --with pointing to the directory for zip usage but no matter what I get this on pipeline build:

```
checking libzip... no
configure: error: zip support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
2023-05-23T14:44:58.536435778Z stdout P checking for the location of zlib...
```

I've put a solid day and a half into this and can't seem to figure out the issue. Has anyone had this issue with their pipeline builds?

Existing bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
# registry for your build environment.
image: php:7.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip zlib1g-dev git
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - docker-php-ext-install zip
          - php -v
          - composer --version
          - composer install --no-scripts
          - vendor/bin/phpunit --version
          - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

`php:7.0` is pretty ancient, it was end-of-lifed more than 4 years ago. It's built on Debian 9 "Stretch" which was end-of-lifed last year. The apt repositories are no longer maintained, so your `apt update` is not updating anything and your `apt install` is not installing anything. You might be able to find an old pre-built Docker image that already has the needed packages installed, but you'll need to face the inevitable march regardless.

If you want to keep running PHP 7.0, you'll probably have to build your own image, starting from something recent like Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and then compiling PHP 7.0 from source. It's certainly doable but would not be my recommendation. It would likely be less effort to just update your pipeline (and your app) to use PHP 7.4. Note that this is also already past end-of-life, but you'll still be able to get running images of it for a while.

Sooner or later, you're going to have to update your app to PHP 8. If you're having problems doing that, [Rector](https://getrector.com/) can be very helpful.